# Change Resize JTable Header Cursor

Tags: java, header, jtable, cursor

So I know you can change the cursor for the header of a jtable with the following:

```
jTable.getTableHeader().setCursor(MyClient.greenResizeHorizontal);
```

How can you change the horizontal resize cursor between column headers?

--**EDIT**--

Per @MadProgrammer I tried to mess around with UI delegate and was able to change the cursor same way as above.  Still no clue how to change the resize part.  Thoughts anyone?

```
jtable.getTableHeader().setUI(new BasicTableHeaderUI(){
    JTableHeader header;

    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        header = (JTableHeader) c;
        header.setCursor(MyClient.greenResizeHorizontal);

        super.installUI(c);
    }
});
```

Comment: Last time I checked, you'd need to get into the look and feel delegate

Comment: @MadProgrammer just made an edit on the look and feel delegate stuff.  I am now stuck again.  Do you think I need a mouse event to check if I'm between columns?  That seems a bit bloated.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, there is no "good" way to modify this cursor.
`BasicTableHeaderUI` is using default resize cursor, and it contains private static field, named `"resizeCursor"` for that.
Also, Swing `UIManager` does not provide any properties, which would allow to change the cursor (see http://thebadprogrammer.com/swing-uimanager-keys/).

The only way I've found is to modify value of this field with reflection (I'm using hand cursor, any other can be here):

```
table.getTableHeader().setUI(new BasicTableHeaderUI(){
    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        try {
            final Field f = getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("resizeCursor");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(null, Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.installUI(c);
    }
});
```

But this is hacky, and - because it uses privat stuff - it may stop to work with any Java update, and - AFAIR - will not work if jar with your app is signed (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html).